Implementing an Error which is generic over Kind in Rust
I'm attempting to create an Error type which is generic over a provided Kind. Due to orphan rules, I also created a trait IntoKind<K> to transform between Kinds. For my use case, it would be nice if given impl IntoKind<K2> for K1 I could infer From<K1: IntoKind<K2>> for Error<K2>, or perhaps From<Error<K1: IntoKind<K2>>> for Error<K2>.
See https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5bee67e77612b49960338116455467b4
I tried the following snippet. I attempted to use #![feature(negative_impls)] to deny implementations of Kind and IntoKind for Error<K>.
#![feature(negative_impls)]

use std::fmt::{Debug, Display};

pub trait Kind: Debug + Display + Send + Sync + 'static {}

pub trait IntoKind<K: Kind> {
    fn into_kind(self) -> K;
}

impl<K: Kind> IntoKind<K> for K {
    fn into_kind(self) -> K {
        self
    }
}

pub struct Error<K: Kind> {
    kind: K
}

impl<K> !Kind for Error<K> {}
impl<K1: Kind, K2: Kind> !IntoKind<K1> for Error<K2> {}

// Why doesn't the negative impl work?
// Is there a way to make this work?
impl<K2: Kind, K1: IntoKind<K2>> From<K1> for Error<K2> {
    fn from(_kind: K1) -> Self {
        todo!()
    }
}

However, I get the following error:
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `From<Error<_>>` for type `Error<_>`
  --> src/lib.rs:26:1
   |
26 | impl<K2: Kind, K1: IntoKind<K2>> From<K1> for Error<K2> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
           - impl<T> From<T> for T;

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0119`.

I'm not quite sure I understand. This error seems to suggest Error<K> may potentially implement IntoKind, but I was hoping the negative impl may prevent that. Unless I'm completely misunderstanding the error?

The normal way to do this is to have one impl From for every type that can be turned into your Error. The crate thiserror is useful for automating that when your error is an enum. It's discouraged to have generic error types since they can't be composed with each other, so they aren't any more useful than the plain K they contain.

The problem is my plan is to have Error exist in a separate crate, and the consumers of the crate only define their own Kinds, but they use the same base Error to wrap it. Because of the orphan rule, they cannot define their own From implementations for Error, as it exists outside their crate.
Regarding composition, I agree. Technically my Error has it's own variants, one of which is Kind(K) and another other being Other(Box<dyn std::error::Error>) to type erase. Then it uses a combination of feature(error_generic_member_access) and downcasting to extract backtrace, etc.

This is explicitly not supported by negative impls as defined currently, see this comment and it's followup in the tracking issue

"Because of the orphan rule, they cannot define their own From implementations for Error" They can, actually.

I think that IntoKind is superfluous, since we have From<T> and the derived Into<T>. Just implement From<T> for any type T: Kind where generically applicable.

@RichardNeumann You are correct, it seems I was making things overly complicated as I usually do.
I originally had a signature like:
impl<K1: Kind, K2: From<K1> + Kind> From<K1> for Error<K2>
Which was conflicting against
impl<K: Kind> From<K> for Error<K>
I made the mistake of going down this rabbit hole of introducing a separate IntoKind trait, instead of just deleting the second impl. Whoops!
There may be a problem with a trait conflict since there is nothing preventing the user from implementing From<Error<K1>> for K2, but I'll cross that bridge when I come to it.

I read through the rules regarding trait coherence and I don't think what I'm trying to achieve is possible under those rules. What I didn't understand is  a trait like IntoKind is very different from a trait like IntoKind<K>. Orphan rules will disallow externally implementing a non-generic trait like IntoKind for Error<K>, but will allow implementation of IntoKind<K> for Error<K>.
